# typhoeus hydra won't fire parallely

Tags: ruby, typhoeus, hydra

I am using typhoeus hydra

```
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new(max_concurrency: 10)        
links.each_with_index do |link, i| 
                req = Typhoeus::Request.new("#{link}") 
                req.on_complete do |res|
                    puts "doing #{i} out of #{links.size}"
                    threadJob(res.body, i, products)                    
                end
                hydra.queue req
            end
```

However, when I run it (hydra.run)
it seems as if it is running one by one...

What can be the issue?
Thanks

Comment: It's not. It is running in parallel. I guess `puts`s are printed one by one because every request takes different time to execute. Do the benchmark and you will see that this implementation is faster then usual loop.

Comment: You can install Charles Web Proxy and check your version